# jQuery if..else conditional statements based on hash id extracted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<section>
  <div class="main" id="second"> </div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="main" id="third"></div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="main" id="fourth"></div>
</section>
```

And following jQuery code:

```
<script>
navlist = [];
$("#navlist a").each(function(i) {
    var thisLink = $(this);
    var thisId = thisLink.attr('href');
    var thisTarget = $(thisId);
    navlist.push({
        'anchor': thisLink,
        'id': thisId,
        'target': thisTarget
    });
    thisLink.on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: thisTarget.offset().top
        }, 800);
    });
});
$(window).on('scroll resize', function(e) {
    $.each(navlist, function(e, elem) {
        var placement = elem.target[0].getBoundingClientRect();
        if( placement.top<window.innerHeight && placement.bottom>0 ) {
            history.pushState({}, '', elem.id);
            console.log('Hash: ' + elem.id);
            return false; /* Exit $.each loop */
        };
    });
});
</script>
```

The work of the script is to allow smooth scrolling between different anchors on the site and to change URL #id on click or on scroll. I want to use here conditional statements with the id grabbed from the URL.

For example:

```
if(grabbedhashid == "second"){
    $(".phone").css('display', 'none');
}else{
   //display

}
```

But I am not having any idea as from where I can do it. Please help me guys.

Example URL with ID: `http://localhost/sites/fh/index.php#first`

Comment: can you share your one of the URL with id

Comment: code snippet or fiddle would be better

Comment: @ÖzgürErsil updated... but its only for idea and not for viewing as its on localhost..

Comment: @ShubhamJha Your localhost wont be accessible outside, better is make fiddle or pen using jsfiddle.net or codepen.io

Comment: @VilasKumkar see the answer by Özgür Ersil I need something like that.. it will give you an idea..

Comment: @ShubhamJha If you could have share fiddle with problem you are facing, you might have got the rid of your problem by now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically you have it in your scroll function, use that script to hide phone only in `#second`, it will work for you

```
 $(window).on('scroll resize', function(e) {
        $.each(navlist, function(e, elem) {
            var placement = elem.target[0].getBoundingClientRect();
            if (placement.top < window.innerHeight && placement.bottom > 0) {
                history.pushState({}, '', elem.id);
                console.log('Hash: ' + elem.id);
                if(elem.id == "#second"){
                   $(".phone").css('display', 'none');
                }else{
                   $(".phone").css('display', 'block');
              }
            return false; /* Exit $.each loop */
            };

        });
 });
```

Comment: yes something like this.. now where to place this code in my jquery code to make it work?

Comment: on your scroll function

Comment: ok and instead of using those two lines can't I just use window.location.hash and store it in id?

Comment: I made a separate block of this code `$(document).ready(function(){
 var idSample = window.location.href.split("#");
 var id = "#"+idSample[1];
 if(id == "first"){
  $(".phone").hide();
 }else{
  $(".phone").show();
 }
});` 

but this is not working...

Comment: Here it is.. I don't want that phone image to be seen on 1st section https://jsfiddle.net/shubhamjha1000/vh7bu32q/

Comment: yes it is.. thanks.. but can you help me add this effect like fueled.com has? have a look on the website plz... :)

Comment: correction needed.. what if no #tag is there in URL? in that case the image must not show even. Need to add this check..

Comment: if it is empty means never #second , so your image will be visible, no problem

Comment: for the effect you can use scroll percentage with opacity in `if(elem.id == "#second")` block

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get current browser url at the time of scroll/click, you can get them as below. Use some string filter function like(window.location.href.split("#");) if you want to filter out only #id part.

JavaScript :

```
 //using href
 var URL = window.location.href;
 //using path
 var URL = window.location.pathname;
```

Jquery :

```
 $(location).attr('href');
```